# How can I add roles to a user during the authentication process by using a custom authentication process in ASPnet Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core, authorization

I recently picked up a dotnet web app that I need to update. The app authenticates the user with windows auth without problem. But there aren't any roles and I need to add role-based authorization to the app.

The problem is, in my organisation, the user roles are centralized via a webservice.

Do I need to setup the entire Identity framework even though I don't want any user info to be stored in the app ? Or is there a simple solution to customize the authentification process and run custom code on user auth ?

Summary of what I want to happen :

1 - User connects to website

2 - Server has user ID from windows auth (already works)

3 - Server makes a request to an external webservice with the user ID to get the user's roles

4 -  User is now authenticated with roles

I've found older answers describing a Custom Role Provider, but it doesn't seem like that particular architecture exist anymore in aspnet core 6.0 MVC ...

Worst case I can just do it manually by calling a function to check the user's roles before every controller call, but I'm asking here before doing that in case there is a more elegant solution I have missed.

I also have trouble distinguishing all the different .NET versions so if you suspect that I am using the wrong version, or misunderstand what version I am using, please advise.